# Catching Javamail Exceptions

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am planning on using javamail to sent automated emails in a loop type fashion. So for example I might have 300 emails that I need to build and send out with javamail one after the other. I am using timers in java to automate the process at a specific time each day.

What exceptions should I attempt to catch and how do I handle the error when I do catch an exception without interrupting the loop? What exceptions should I expect to run into? Unable to connect to SMTP server? Invalid email address? Etc?

Comment: how do you expect us to comment on this without knowing anything about your code?

Comment: You could always catch `Exception`...although that's bad practice.  What exceptions could come up using Javamail?  Consult their API to double-check, then consider handling those cases with appropriate logic.

Comment: Its not really a code type question. I'll update the question to be a little more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to put the try/catch inside the loop.  If you want the loop to keep going, you should just log the exception and process the next attempt.

As for which exceptions to catch, you'll be forced to catch all the checked ones.  If you don't want unchecked exceptions to interrupt the processing you'll have to catch those, too.  I would not go so far as to catch `Throwable`.

Comment: I guess I should have been a little clearer in the question. What type of exceptions should I expect to have to catch? Unable to connect to smtp server? Invalid email? etc?

Comment: The javadocs will show that you need to catch MessagingException.  There are many subclasses of MessagingException; the javadocs should tell you which ones might be thrown from which methods.  If you want to try to "recover" from the exception, you'll need to handle many of the subclasses.  But to answer your question, yes, many things can go wrong, including failing to connect to your server, invalid email addresses, etc.